# Were Neandertals as Hairy as We Are?

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, hair

What I mean to say regards facial and androgenic hairs.  There are many theories as to why some people have both kinds of hairs, while others have one or the same and others still have neither.  The best and most popular guess is that those hairs were secondary sexual organs, meaning that they just make the boys more attractive to the girls.

It's a well-known fact that hair provides insulation, and in the last ice age, Europe was dominated by a hominid built specifically to deal with the cold.  I am talking about, of course, the Neandertal.  Is there any evidence that the Neandertals, as a means of adaptations against the cold, were equipped with body hair?  If not, then would it be safe to speculate on such?

Comment: It is a good question (+1). You may want to have a look at [this webpage](http://evoandproud.blogspot.ca/2012/01/were-neanderthals-furry.html) for a quick summary of the discussion and different arguments about how hairy was *H. neanderthalis*. There are other threads online that explain more or less that there is no definitive answer but I failed to find a review in a peer-reviewed journal.

Comment: Just a detail about the form of the post: When you say `There are many theories`, (1) the correct term is "hypothesis", not "theory" and (2) you should link to a detailed explanation for hypothesis (or evidence if there is any in the post) that you talk about, especially when these aren't well known.